# How to loop a JSONArray in JSP page and display each record in div tag?

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring, jsp

I am new to spring MVC. I am just trying my first application using Spring MVC. I am able to fetch data from a News API and the problem is i need to send the collection of News in JSONArray to a JSP. The JSONArray needs to be looped and each record to be set in a div tag.

Below is the code i have tried.

```
@RequestMapping("/FetchNews")
public ModelAndView FetchNews(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {

    String URI="http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=API-KEY";

    ResponseParser rp=new ResponseParser();
    JSONArray resp=rp.getLatestNews(URI);
    System.out.println("Response=="+resp);

    ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("News.jsp");
    mv.addObject("NewsArrayObject", resp);
    return mv;

}
```

From the "News.jsp" page i need to loop the "resp" JSONArray to set each record in a Div tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:forEach items="${NewsArrayObject}" var="item"></c:forEach>
```

Also set

```
@RequestMapping("/FetchNews", headers="Accept=application/json")
```